# how to create 7incs avd emulator in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I would like to create a 7inchs avd with android api 4.0.X.

how can i create 7inchs tablet emulator to test the app with android version 4.0

please any body help me

Answer (score 0):

To get the official Samsung Galaxy Tab emulator do the following:

1) Open the Android SDK and AVD Manager

2) Click on Available packages

3) Expand the Third party Add-ons. There you will see Samsung Electronics add-ons.

4) Once the add-on is installed create a new emulator. Under Target you will see the new Samsung Tab settings, select that.

That's it!

Create a emulator with 1024x600 size and OS version 4.0 thats is similar to Tab 7"

Comment: i am looking for android 4.0 version tablet emulator the samsung electronic add-ons is not an android 4.0 version